# Adding side bar "Shop by Brands" in Bigcommerce stencil theme

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm trying to add a shop by brand to a Bigcommerce theme. I've been through the template files and can't seem to make out what I need to do. I found the "shop-by-price.html" template page and I figured I could just paste some code above it but can't seem to find the brand listing code.

Here's the shop-by-price.html page

```
{{#if shop_by_price}}
  <div class="sidebar-block shop-by-price facet-list" data-facet-filter>
    {{> components/common/facet-toggle title=(lang 'category.shop_by_price')}}
    <ul class="facet-list-items is-open" data-facet-filter-wrapper>
      {{#each shop_by_price}}
        <li class="facet-item">
          <a class="{{#if selected }}is-active{{/if}}" href="{{url}}" alt="{{low.formatted}} - {{high.formatted}}">{{low.formatted}} - {{high.formatted}}</a>
        </li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
    {{#any shop_by_price selected=true}}
      <a href="{{category_url}}" class="link facet-remove">
        {{lang 'category.reset'}}
      </a>
    {{/any}}
  </div>
{{/if}}
```

Comment: check screenshot : http://prntscr.com/ez0t23

Comment: is that screenshot reflective of what's down there.... the code?

Comment: you can check the website now.

Answer (score 1):

if I am not wrong so you want to show brands list in category sidebar page so please open your stencil theme editor from admin end then 
 ***templates->components->category->sidebar.html*** open the file sidebar.html and paste below code

```
<nav>
    {{#if category.subcategories}}
    <div class="sidebarBlock">
        <h5 class="sidebarBlock-heading">{{category.name}}</h5>
        <ul class="navList">
            {{#each category.subcategories}}
            <li class="navList-item">
                <a class="navList-action" href="{{url}}" alt="{{name}}" title="{{name}}">{{name}}</a>
            </li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
    {{/if}}
{{#if shop_by_brand}}
        <div class="sidebarBlock">
            <h5 class="sidebarBlock-heading">{{lang 'brand.label'}}</h5>
            <ul class="navList">
                {{#each shop_by_brand}}
                    <li class="navList-item">
                        <a class="navList-action" href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a>
                    </li>
                {{/each}}
                <li class="navList-item">
                    <a class="navList-action" href="{{urls.brands}}">{{lang 'common.view_all'}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        {{/if}}
    {{#if category.faceted_search_enabled}}
        {{> components/faceted-search/index category}}
    {{else}}
        {{> components/category/shop-by-price shop_by_price=category.shop_by_price category_url=category.url}}
    {{/if}}

</nav>
```

after hit the save and apply button it will look like this 
http://deepak-diwan-s-store.mybigcommerce.com/ala-carte-by-the-lb/

Comment: the site you sent me to doesn't have a side bar, just a page with a bunch of items on it

Comment: sorry, i have made some changes please check it now.